# All about SharePoint licences

Tags: 2010, sql-server, windows-server, licensing, small-business-server

My question is regarding the licensing of the SharePoint, basically there was already a topic done about it, but it had just bunch of references to website which i already saw and i still didnt get my question answered. That is why i write here a new post.

This is not only about SharePoint but rather everything you need to run SharePoint.

Basically what you need:

- Windows Server 2008 R2
- Sql Server 2008 Standard
- SharePoint Foundation | Server 2010 (Standard)

Having this noted i was trying to find out the prices for this products but I couldn't, can't i buy those products and CAL's for them on Microsoft Website? i didnt find atleast any good link?

Now back to the question:
So if i want to run a SharePoint for my company which is small and has lets says 20 employees which will perfrom basic operations on SharePoint, so lets agree in this case for foundation.

**Foundation:**

- You install Windows Server 2008 R2 and for each user you have to buy
  CAL so it will be 20 CAL's.
- You install SQL Server 2008 Standard, do I also have to buy 20 CAL's
  for it, or only one, because only one entity basically sharepoint
  will contact with it?
- And then we have a SharePoint Foundation which is free.

So in general it will cost me WS2008 + 20 * CAL's + SQL + 1 * CAL ???

**SharePoint Standard**

- Windows Server
- SQL Server + 1 CAL
- SharePoint Standard + 20 CAL's

In this solution, windows server will not have CAL's but SharePoint will right? OR should I buy CAL's for both Windows Server and SharePoint standard?

**Windows Small Business Server Premium Add-on** I found out on the microsoft site that this server exists, which contains in it self Windows Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008, basically only have this will work right?  Or is it not good enough to run SharePoint on?

All that licensing is a bit complicated.

And another very important question:

If I buy all those licenses are they for ever? Or only for one year and then I should renew them?

And how does the Microsoft checks it? For example I bought 20 CAL's but then a new user came to my company i add him to AD and what if he doesn't have CAL he will not be able to access intranet site, how is it being verified?

Answer (score 1):

Shkipper,

First you need to understand what is CAL:
CAL means **Client Access License**... and it doesn't need to be equivalent to the number of users in your company, lets say you have 20 employees in your company but only 5 of them connect concurrently on SharePoint then you need only 5 CAL's not 20!

About verifying these CAL's... There is no such limitation that new users won't be able to access Intranet if they don't have CAL's, its just being fair of what you are using you have the proper license to it! Let's say you have a gun but you don't have its license, then you are afraid of being caught but if you have license you are pretty confident... Its exactly the same, Microsoft/Partners of Microsoft randomly visit your company and check these licenses, so if you want to play fair you must buy required licenses!

SharePoint Foundation as you said is completely free and you don't need any SharePoint license if you are planning to use SharePoint Foundation in your environment... and SharePoint Foundation installs SQL Server Express Instance which again is free, so if you are planning to test the usage of SharePoint and getting your people familiar with it - its best to go for these free versions!

However, I don't have enough information on Windows Server and SQL Server Licenses, so may be someone else will be answering about those! :)

The answer may not be appropriate because it truly depends on my personal experience!

I hope this helps!

Comment: Good to know it was helpful :)