# How to determine SharePoint 2010 Licensing needs for development and deployment?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, licensing

- Need to know if we have different licenses available for SharePoint development and actual application deployment for clients to use. For developement can I use MSDN license?
- For deployment for clients to use - I need enterprise SharePoint 2010 and want to deploy my solutions internally which will be accessed by all the employees in the organization. Say we have 12,000 employees. Can you please confirm if following will be my licensing requirements -
       I will be using one Enterprise server license
       And need 12,000 Standard and Enterprise CAL licenses?
  Also I need excel services and office web apps. Can you please let me know which licenses will be required for the same?

If anyone knows costs for the above two also please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, i also had to do some research on the licensing and it is all so complicated, still didnt really understood everything. But as long as i know, yes you will have to have and SharePoint Eneterprise Licence and CAL's for concurrent user connections. As well than for SQL Server, the excel servcie licenses i think are embedded with the office tools.

Comment: This might be a good link for both of you: http://www.microsoft.com/licensing/about-licensing/client-access-license.aspx and also http://www.microsoftvolumelicensing.com/userights/ProductPage.aspx?pid=80

Comment: so do we have seperate license for sharepoint development and is it part of MSDN?

Answer (score 0):

SPDeveloper,

A similar question is answered here:
[All about SharePoint licences](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50414/all-about-sharepoint-licences/50427)

However, why don't you use SharePoint Enterprise Trial [180 days] for your development...
[Download link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9449)

Part of the question answered I guess :)

Comment: Thanks. I am already using the trial version and getting closer to the expiry period. can you please let me know about the developer license for SharePoint as part of MSDN subscription?

Comment: I have never heard of Developer License for SharePoint, do you have any link where Microsoft offers Developer License ?